# When doing a FSBO, do you usually offer a percentage of the sale for real estate agents to bring their clients?

Tags: real-estate, fees

When doing a FSBO, do you usually offer a percentage of the sale for real estate agents to bring their clients?

I'm wondering of I should use a for-sale-by-owner (FSBO) site or just list my house in MLS.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way agents get paid is that when the seller lists a house with an agent, the seller commits to a 6% commission.  **The sellers agent splits that with the buyer’s agent 50/50, or 3% each**.  (Now on some markets it’s less than 6% because home prices are unusually high. As an FSBO it is your job to know if that’s so.)

Anyway, if you list on an MLS, you might get inquiries from buyer’s agents about the commission you will pay them.  If it is not competitive, **no agent will show your house**.

You will not get that exposure, and it will slow your sale.

Now you might say “how about the buyer pay the buyer’s agent”.   That has 2 problems.

First, it guarantees the buyer will reduce their offer by *at least* 3% and probably more.

Second, buyers typically don’t have the cash.  it is usually essential to buyers that they fold as many closing costs into the mortgage as possible.  That is why buyers do weird things like have sellers do renovations instead of just lowering their offer.

FSBO is a lot harder than it looks. There are 100 things like that.

Comment: There are an increasing number of fixed fee or discount home sellers though, and 6% is a huge chunk of money in many markets, so don't accept it just because that's what other people are used to.

Comment: @Hart CO  So are you suggesting to "shop around" for fees or ask an agent to possibly take less?  Or did you mean there are discount RE agents for use?

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica  "harder than it looks".  But isn't the savings worth it or are you suggesting that there are possibly legal or logistical issues that make it pointless?

Comment: Can’t say. Deciding the value of your time and the learning you’d do,  is something only you can do.